# Firebase Firestore Sum of 3 Random Document Fields Below a Set Amount

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a weight-loss app that provides the user with multiple recipe options for their daily menu (breakfast, lunch and dinner). The sum of the 3 recipes provided must be under their calorie intake for the day.

At present I am doing this locally in the app with a while loop. I get 3 random recipes, add them up and see if they are below the the allowed calories and continue until I find a combination that is suitable. Like this:

```
 do {
    // Create a random number for each list to get a random recipe
    int breakfastRandomNumber = Random().nextInt(breakfastRecipes.length);
    int lunchRandomNumber = Random().nextInt(lunchRecipes.length);
    int dinnerRandomNumber = Random().nextInt(dinnerRecipes.length);
   
    Recipe breakfastRecipe = breakfastRecipes[breakfastRandomNumber];
    Recipe lunchRecipe = lunchRecipes[lunchRandomNumber];
    Recipe dinnerRecipe = dinnerRecipes[dinnerRandomNumber];

    if (breakfastRecipe.getCals + lunchRecipe.getCals + dinnerRecipe.getCals <= userDailyCals){
      userMealList.add(breakfastRecipe);
      userMealList.add(lunchRecipe);
      userMealList.add(dinnerRecipe);
      recipesAdded++;
    }
  }
  while(recipesAdded < 1);
```

In Firestore each recipe is stored as an individual document, so if I were to follow this pattern I would have an unknown number of recipe reads with the while loop.

My current thought is to keep a seperate master doc with all the recipes (just the ids and calories). Read that document first and do the while loop through that to find the recipes to download and display.

Is this there any other way to do this and keep my read count low?

Thanks

Comment: Im no expert, but for me the idea you are presenting sounds fine. Maybe we can find a way to have less data reads by adding a categories tag of the receipts for example so we can split them in firestore so that we only need to read the "seperate master doc" which only contains veggie receipts for example.

Comment: Doing that as well, thanks Marcel